# How to disable xaml optimization in windows 10 uwp?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

I'm developing a windows 10 uwp app. I have a gridview which contains images and are bound at run-time dynamically from the c# end but when i scroll down fast sometimes and scroll up again some images disappear leaving a blank spot.I have done the same in windows phone 8.1 without any problem but here I think there is some xaml optimization, hence was wondering how to disable this?

XAML Code:

```
  <GridView x:Name="gv" Margin="8,0,8,8" 
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  SizeChanged="GridView_SizeChanged" 
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="gv_ItemClick"
                  SelectionMode="Single">
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail,Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

And from the a value converter I'm getting images and converting them to Bitmap Image for Binding.
Image for reference[image]

Comment: It is bad idea to disable virtualization. It can cause performance issues and memory leaks. I you really want it, then try set `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` on your GridView.

Comment: @RavingDev : I'm not getting a reference to  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualozing property. Can you give a reference?

Comment: Or, it is my mistake. Try set diffrerent values to VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode. Then google how to disable wirtualization for GridView.

Comment: I believe this property does not exists in WinRT, I think its a WPF property.

Comment: If could set the itemspanel to something that has no vitualization `<ListView>
 <ListView.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel></StackPanel>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
 </ListView>`

Comment: So I cant use GridView? As I was using the same code and had a different behavior on windows phone 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I solved this by surrounding the `<GridView>`with a `<ScrollViewer>`.This will disable the gridview optimization. Please note this is a workaround and and can affect the performance of the gridview in other ways. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: Hello, have you found a permanent solution? I am having a very similar issue when I scroll really quickly. But instead of blank spaces, my images are getting scrambled i.e. Item #1 has Item #4's image, and #4 has #7's image, etc. The scrambling is somewhat random. I really hope to solve this without disabling UI virtualization.